# SQL Recursive Loop (Product Structure / BOM)

Tags: sql, sql-server, common-table-expression, recursive-query

I am in need of building a recursive loop to spit out a product structure/BOM for products in my DB.

I have two primary tables that contain the data.  The first is ps_mstr which contains the product structures.  The primary fields in this table are:

ps_par (Parent Part Number)
ps_comp (Component Part Number)
ps_qty_per (Quantity of Component in Parent)
ps_end_date (End Date of Component in Parent -- this should be NULL)

The other table is pt_mstr.  This table contains the part information and the link can be between the ps_par OR ps_comp in the ps_mstr table.  The primary fields in this table are:

pt_part (Part Number)
pt_pm_code (Manufactured Code, either P, M, or L.  I'll explain shortly).
pt_desc1 (Part Description)

The reason we need the pt_mstr table is because we need to drill down until we reach the 'P' code for pt_pm_code.  Anything other than 'P' is a manufactured part.  'P' standard for purchased component.

The picture below shows parent part number of 1080003101.  Within this, it consumes several components.  All but one are 'P' or purchased items.  For the one 'M' item Type, we need to drill down to explode this BOM.

[image]

Here is the drilldown of the 1080003101 and the 1080003099 above:

[image]

Within that drill down, we find that there are more non-'P' Type parts, so we need to keep drilling down until we get ALL 'P' Levels:

[image]

I have tried several recursive loops but am unable to get the results I am looking for and am asking for assistance.  Here is the code I am currently trying to use:

```
    USE QadMain;
GO
WITH PartBOM (ps_par, ps_comp, ps_qty_per, pt_pm_code, Level)
AS
(
-- Anchor part definition
    SELECT ps.ps_par, ps.ps_comp, ps.ps_qty_per, pt.pt_pm_code, 0 As Level
    FROM [QadMain].[dbo].[ps_mstr] ps
    LEFT JOIN [QadMain].[dbo].[pt_mstr] pt ON pt.pt_part = ps.ps_comp
    WHERE ps.ps_end IS NULL
    UNION ALL
-- Recursive part definition
    SELECT ps.ps_par, ps.ps_comp, ps.ps_qty_per, pt.pt_pm_code, Level + 1
    FROM [QadMain].[dbo].[ps_mstr] ps
    LEFT JOIN [QadMain].[dbo].[pt_mstr] pt ON pt.pt_part = ps.ps_comp
    WHERE pt.pt_pm_code <> 'P' AND ps.ps_end IS NULL
)

-- Statement that executes the CTE
SELECT ps_par, ps_comp, ps_qty_per, pt_pm_code, Level
FROM PartBOM
GO
```

Answer (score 0):

The recursive CTE requires a self-reference in the recursive part of the definition. That means, you need to join with PartBOM. Without that, you've just got a regular CTE.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, Nik.  I think I understand, but could you provide an example of what you refer to?

Comment: Can you provide a script to generate a little bit of sample data? I can probably help you with the query if I have something to work with.

Comment: Nik, what sample data would you like to see?

Comment: The two main tables you describe above and a product that has a couple of levels of subparts. Two table definitions and some INSERT statements should do it. Basically what you have in the images, but in script form